# Spacy - Force POS tag for quoted text

Tags: nlp, spacy

I want Spacy to treat quoted text as e.g. a NOUN or PROPN so that it forms a compound with the adjacent word. For example in the following text I want the text "drink me" to be attached to the word "label".

```
Find the bottle which has the label "drink me".
```

I can successfully merge all the text inside the quotes into a single token but the token is simply tagged as PUNCT (since this is the POS of the first token of the merged group) but then it gets inserted in the wrong place in the dependency tree. I need to be able to modify the POS so that it goes to the right place in the tree.

[image: dependency tree]

Answer (score 0):

The POS and where it's attached in the tree are to some extent separate problems.

You can provide the POS for the merged token as part of the merge method, e.g.:

```py
# tested with spacy==3.5.0
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp('Find the bottle which has the label "drink me".')

with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    retokenizer.merge(doc[7:11], attrs={"POS": "NOUN"})
```

Otherwise the merge method uses the dependency tree to decide which POS to use for the merged token (so not necessarily the first token).

If you want the head of `"drink me"` to be `label`, you can change this manually after merging:

```py
doc[7].head = doc[6]
```

Ideally you'd be able to add something like `{"HEAD": 6}` to the attributes so you don't need to do it separately, but I tried out with v3.5.0 and it's buggy so I wouldn't recommend doing it that way right now.

You can also edit the dependency tree before merging if that's easier. As long as the subtree for `"drink me"` is attached to `label` instead of `find`, it should stay that way after it's merged.